# Avoiding HttpClient related exceptions in Android for interrupted downloads

Tags: android, xml, json, http, ioexception

First, it seems there is really no great way to test this but I am anticipating errors occurring on an actual device that I cannot see in an emulator, specifically a drop in the Network and/or Wifi that cuts internet access in a download of a file or JSON/XML data in Android. Specifically I want to handle the situation where it drops mid download.

First I am curious what exception will be thrown in that scenario. I think it would be an IO exception but I'm not completely sure. I am not necessarily sure if it would throw that exception if it received at least some data?

Next I'm not sure exactly how to handle that situation? Use a program to resume the download or timeout after a certain amount of time? Does anyone have experience with this handling this situation that could point me in a good direction?

Further, what other errors might be wise to anticipate for Http?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the execute method, it will throw an IOException per the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html#execute%28org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest%29).  The easiest way to handle the situation is to catch the exception, clear any temp data that may have been stored, and notify the user that he/she needs to re-download whatever it was.

Your app can periodically retry if this is not a user initiated download.  You should also always have some timeouts set for connecting.

One thing you may want to try in the emulator is disabling the network connection of the computer it is running on.  There should be a way to turn off the network connection of the emulator as well, though I'm not well versed in it.